# How to Copy directory folder to with in sub directory except specified folder in java?

Tags: java

I want to move parent folder subfolders to another parent subfolder using java ,below is the folder structure.

```
Source Dir : C:\Users\xxxxx\git\project\Parent
Desctinaton Dir: C:\Users\xxxxx\git\project\Parent\oldParent

Parent
       oldParent
Subdolder1
Subfolder2
```

Now i want to move Subfolder1,2 into oldParent folder.I'm using below code to move but it is not working

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
    public static void move(File sourceDir,File destinationDir){
            
            try {
               // FileUtils.copyDirectory(sourceDir, destinationDir);
                FileUtils.moveDirectory(sourceDir, destinationDir);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            
        }
```

## Exception:

```
org.apache.commons.io.FileExistsException: Destination C:\Users\xxxxx\git\project\Parent\oldParent already exists
```

Comment: "it is not working" is not a problem description. That code looks ok. Is any exception being caught?

Comment: org.apache.commons.io.FileExistsException: Destination C:\Users\xxxxx\git\project\Parent\oldParent already exists..This exception is coming,i've added source and parent directories path

Comment: and what do you think the exception is trying to tell you?

Answer (score 0):

I've modified little bit code,just added and after moving files ,not deleting the files ,then i've used below code,Now it is moving the folders and deleting the folders after move.

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
 public static void moveDirectory(File sourceDir, File destinationDir) throws IOException {
        FileUtils.copyDirectory(sourceDir, destinationDir);

try {

            File directory = new File(sourceDir);
            File[] subdirs = directory.listFiles((FileFilter) DirectoryFileFilter.DIRECTORY);
            for (File dir : subdirs) {
                // System.out.println("Directory: " + dir.getName());
                String name = dir.getName();
                if (!name.equalsIgnoreCase(folderName)) {
                    FileUtils.forceDelete(new File(folderPath + name));
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```